# Keep specific case of function unevaluated until defined while general case is defined

Tags: evaluation

I'm solving a particular differential equation and I have the Laplace transform of y[t], Y[s]. Naturally, my next step is `y[t_]=InverseLaplaceTransform[Y[s],s,t]`.

The problem is that this is a general solution, so the Laplace Transform has a term with `y[0]` in it, so this final step recurses forever. I've tried replacing `y[0]` with `Hold[y[0]]`, `Defer[y[0]]`, `Inactive[y[0]]`, and these all cause `y[t]` to print nicely later, but something I'd like to be able to do later is to derive a specific solution by either writing `y[0]=5; y[t]` or `y[t]/.y[0]->5`.

Is there any way to keep `y[0]` unevaluated until I replace or define it, or should I give up and just use a constant like `y0`?

Comment: Can't test it at the moment, but does `y[t: Except[0]]=Inverse…` do what you want?

Comment: It totally does! Thanks!